# How can I pull from remote Git repository and override the changes in my local repository?

Tags: git

I need to throw away all the changes in my local repository and pull all the code from the remote repository. What is the Git command to do this?

Comment: Here's a way: `git checkout -- .`

Comment: `git fetch origin your_branch && git rebase origin/your_branch` specially helpful in case of git submodules.

Answer (score 437, accepted):

Provided that the remote repository is origin, and that you're interested in master:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This tells it to fetch the commits from the remote repository, and position your working copy to the tip of its master branch.

All your local commits not common to the remote will be gone.

Comment: Note if you are using a new repo github changed origin/master to origin/main
Source: https://www.theserverside.com/feature/Why-GitHub-renamed-its-master-branch-to-main

Answer (score 13):

As an addendum, if you want to reapply your changes on top of the remote, you can also try:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

If you then want to undo some of your changes (but perhaps not all of them) you can use:

```
git reset SHA_HASH
```

Then do some adjustment and recommit.