# Git confusion - how to revert local changes to latest remote push?

Tags: git, git-revert

I have a local git repository, but things get wrong and complicated and I simply want to overwrite all the files in my local directory with the latest version of what is on the remote repository. This would be like a clone, but for an already setup local git repository.

For example: if use `git pull`, then I don't get locally deleted folders back from the remote.

Is it `checkout` that I must use? But how to tell it to retrieve the files from a remote (and not from the stage) and overwrite all?

Comment: Take a look:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284809/how-to-pull-from-remote-git-repository-and-override-the-changes-in-my-local-repo

Comment: Thank you ! To the person who downvoted my question : I did a long search before (not only on Stackoverflow), but did not found this answer. And for some reason the first line of my question got deleted after I edited it (I can't even add a "Hi, ", it gets deleted o_O)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You probably want to use `git reset`.  Assuming you have done a `git fetch` recently, the following will discard everything in your local and reset it to the point you specify as the final argument (in this case the current HEAD of the `origin/master` remote tracking branch):

```
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: If there are no commits in local master, Just `git checkout master` should work

Comment: No, checking out master will not work if you are already on master. The files remain changed. You need to git reset --hard origin/master